# textmate matlab.tmbundle transpose operator

Tags: textmate, matlab

The matlab.tmbundle for textmate seems to consider a single quote ' as the beginning of a quote instead of the transpose operator. I couldn't really find a solution online and I am dubious that the developers would miss such an obvious feature.

Any way to fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been supported for a while now

[image: transpose]

Answer (score 0):

Judging from some occurances on the internet it seems like the developers noticed the problem. However, the current status is not quite clear.

This [commit](http://www.ohloh.net/p/matlab-tmbundle/commits?time_span=30%20days) suggests that it may have been solved, and that the problem can occur if you are using an older/different version.

If the problem still occurs you may be able to file a bug report. If you are really devoted you can of course use `transpose()` rather than a quote but this is quite an intrusive workaround.